# Im not able to access a function (which is in a class) from main, using an array of pointers

Tags: c++, arrays, class, pointers, object

This is my dice.h

```
class Dice
{
public:
int value;
int nrOfFaces;
Dice();
void toss();
};
```

this is my dice.cpp

```
//this is the default constructor (has no parameter)

Dice::Dice()
{
nrOfFaces = 6;
value = rand() % nrOfFaces + 1;
}

//this function gives the dice a new random value

void Dice::toss()
{
value = rand() % nrOfFaces + 1;

}
```

To explain a bit on what Im trying to do here. I'll post the code which is in the main at the bottom of this post. In the main code, Im stuck at the part where, as you can see, I declare an array of pointers. Now, Im trying to first toss the 5 dices in one foor loop. and in the other foor loop Im trying to print out the 5 dice's value. But the way Im doing that doesnt seem to work. I dont get error but the program breaks when it gets to pYatzy[i]->toss();

Here is my main.cpp

```
int main()
{
_CrtSetDbgFlag(_CRTDBG_ALLOC_MEM_DF | _CRTDBG_LEAK_CHECK_DF);

//type cast is done in the c++ way
srand(static_cast<unsigned>(time(NULL)));

Dice *dice1 = new Dice;

cout << dice1->value << endl << endl;

dice1->toss();

cout << dice1->value << endl << endl;


for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{

    dice1->toss();
    cout << dice1->value;
    cout << " ";

}

Dice *pYatzy[5];

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{

    pYatzy[i]->toss();

}

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{

}

system("pause>nul");
return 0;
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Here you make 5 uninitialized pointers:

```
 Dice *pYatzy[5];
```

and here you dereference the uninitialized pointers, which causes undefined behaviour:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    pYatzy[i]->toss();
```

A simple solution would be to replace that code with:

```
Dice pYatzy[5];
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    pYatzy[i].toss();
```

Also, earlier on in your code you could write `Dice  dice1; dice1.toss();` etc., instead of using `new`. There is no need to use `new` 99% of the time in C++ .

Comment: Im just using "new" becuase the teacher instructions asked us to. The code you just wrote, is that still an array of pointers? I kinda used that to begin with becuase I know an array is already a pointer. Is that it?

Comment: @TarikNeaj no it's an array of objects. If you really want an array of pointers you will have to loop through and call `new` 5 times .

Comment: Yes, I need to first declare an array of 5 Dice pointers. Then I have to toss those 5 dices, and then print out their values. Could you show me how to do this? Ive been up all night studying and trying out things.

Comment: Inside your loop put `pYatzy[i] = new Dice;` . You can't toss a dice until you have created it.

Comment: This makes much more sense now that I see how it works. Ive done just that, and I think I have added a random number (the toss function) to all 5 of them (I will post the code here soon). But Now Im trying to print out the values of those 5 pointers, but instead Im getting their adresses, Ive tried using * but doesnt allow me to print that out.           I'll leave a link to  a screenshot of the code, I tried posting it here but didint work out. - http://gyazo.com/299d355814c2796d4f643a7c4550cbd2

Comment: @Tarik Neaj To print out the values of those 5 pointers, put `printf("%d\n", pYatzy[i]->value);` inside your loop .

Comment: @PureProgrammer he is currently printing the value of the pointers, your code prints the value of the `value` variable which represents the number rolled by the dice  (which is indeed what he wants)